# Ensure a long running task is only fired once and subsequent request are queued but with only one entry in the queue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a compute intensive method `Calculate` that may run for a few seconds, requests come from multiple threads.

Only one `Calculate` should be executing, a subsequent request should be queued until the initial request completes.  If there is already a request queued then the the subsequent request can be discarded (as the queued request will be sufficient)

There seems to be lots of potential solutions but I just need the simplest.

**UPDATE:** Here's my rudimentaryattempt:

```
private int _queueStatus;
private readonly object _queueStatusSync = new Object();

public void Calculate()
{
    lock(_queueStatusSync)
    {
        if(_queueStatus == 2) return;
        _queueStatus++;
        if(_queueStatus == 2) return;
    }
    for(;;)
    {
        CalculateImpl();
        lock(_queueStatusSync)
            if(--_queueStatus == 0) return;

    }
}

private void CalculateImpl()
{
    // long running process will take a few seconds...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest, cleanest solution IMO is using `TPL Dataflow` (as always) with a `BufferBlock` acting as the queue. `BufferBlock` is thread-safe, supports `async-await`, and more important, has `TryReceiveAll` to get all the items at once. It also has `OutputAvailableAsync` so you can wait asynchronously for items to be posted to the buffer. When multiple requests are posted you simply take the last and forget about the rest:

```
var buffer = new BufferBlock<Request>();
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (await buffer.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        IList<Request> requests;
        buffer.TryReceiveAll(out requests);
        Calculate(requests.Last());
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
buffer.Post(new Request());
buffer.Post(new Request());
```

---

**Edit:** If you don't have any input or output for the `Calculate` method you can simply use a `boolean` to act as a switch. If it's true you can turn it off and calculate, if it became true again while `Calculate` was running then calculate again:

```
public bool _shouldCalculate;

public void Producer()
{
    _shouldCalculate = true;
}

public async Task Consumer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (!_shouldCalculate)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
        else
        {
            _shouldCalculate = false;
            Calculate();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Calculate` is currently a void method with no parameters, I can't seem to get your code to work. I'm guessing Linqpad isn't the best place to test async stuff!

Comment: @DogEars TPL Dataflow is a Nuget library, you need to add that first. But if Calculate has no input or output, there's no need for a queue. Just have a bool which is set to true on requests and set to false when you calculate.

Comment: I've got the nuget package added to LinqPad.. We need to ensure that if a Calculation is in progress.. subsequent requests will get executed, so a "queue" of 1 is required I think , but it doesn't have to store anything.. just a record of the outstanding request.

Comment: @DogEars It can simply turn on that bool which represents a request to be made

Comment: @l3arnon We're getting there! Currently the calculation is done synchronously on the calling thread.. i need to avoid the task.delay we could have dozens of objects that have the Calculate method. I don't really want to have to spawn a 'Consumer' for each one? Isn't this making it more complex. I've updated my rudimentary example simplifying it a bit after what you've suggested. cheers, Ears.

Comment: Instead of active waiting, I think you should use something like `AsyncManualResetEvent`.

Comment: Wouldn't taking the last item in the buffer mean that you process using FILO (first in last out) vs FIFO (first in first out)  ?   If so, could you show an example where FIFO would work.

Comment: @SanuelJackson no. Dataflow blocks are FIFO.

Comment: Isn't there a solution that doesn't require adding a separate NuGet package of unknown size and performance characteristics? There should be plenty of synchronisation tools in the BCL but it's not always obvious how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a classic producer-consumer. I'd recommend looking into [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). It is part of the `System.Collection.Concurrent` namespace. On top of that you can implement your queuing logic.

You may supply to a `BlockingCollection` any internal structure to hold its data, such as a `ConcurrentBag<T>`, `ConcurrentQueue<T>` etc. The latter is the default structure used.

Comment: Can you please explain this in greater detail? I can't make any sense of how that BlockingCollection should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A BlockingCollection that only takes 1 at a time
The trick is to skip if there are any items in the collection

I would go with the answer from I3aron +1
This is (maybe) a BlockingCollection solution

```
public static void BC_AddTakeCompleteAdding()
{
    using (BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>(1))
    {

        // Spin up a Task to populate the BlockingCollection  
        using (Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (bc.TryAdd(i))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("  add  " + i.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("  skip " + i.ToString());
                }

                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
            bc.CompleteAdding();
        }))
        {

            // Spin up a Task to consume the BlockingCollection 
            using (Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // Consume consume the BlockingCollection 
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("take " + bc.Take());
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // An InvalidOperationException means that Take() was called on a completed collection
                    Console.WriteLine("That's All!");
                }
            }))

                Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't thread-safe. Multiple can enter this `if (bc.Count == 0)` and block on `bc.Add(i);`

Comment: @I3arnon OK it think I have to agree with that it is not thread safe. Even in that case just that thread would be blocked until it was cleared - other threads would still skip. You would just get that one out of order. And the question did not indicate adding from multiple threads.

Comment: @I3arnon OK it does say "requests come from multiple threads".  I missed that part.